# What is '$data' in ngtable's HTML page

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using ngtable and at this place in HTML while displaying table

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
```

I do not understand the use of $data, as '$' is not needed in other cases in ng-repeat.

Comment: Use $data inside the HTML code, because this is what accesses getData():

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`ng-table` maintains it's own scope, and `$data` is the data which exists in this scope, rather than your full data set, which is on the scope of the page controller.  It is the property that is populated by the `getData()` function call in the `ngTableParams()` object.

This usage and syntax is deprecated, and has been replaced entirely in the current `ng-table` source, which is now written in TypeScript as of v2.0.0.

Comment: You beat me  i was also looking at the souce code :D +1 for you.

Comment: link in dead please provide new link

Comment: Is there the documentation about this?

Comment: @oshliaer there isn't any documentation still available from what I can find;  This was an old syntax when the question was answered in 2015, and the syntax was deprecated in 2016, so it's unlikely to be currently documented, since it's use is not recommended.