# AngularJS <select> dropdown is empty depending on placement in template

Tags: angularjs

I'm experiencing some peculiar behavior based on the `<select>` tag. It seems that the dropdown is empty depending on where I place it in the template. For example, this works:

```
<div ng-if="admin.editingRole">
  <select ng-options="role.name for role in $data.roles" ng-model="admin.editRole"></select>
</div>
```

But if I include the exact same element in another place:

```
<div>
<label for="role">Role</label>  
 <select ng-options="role.name for role in $data.roles" ng-model="admin.editRole"></select>
</div>
```

The dropdown is empty. I can't for the life of me figure why this would happen.

Comment: Have you any errors in the console? You've likely placed the `select` outside the scope where the `$data` property resides.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - No, there are no errors in the console. I'm new to Angular, though, I was under the impression that $data is available in my entire template. Is that incorrect?

Comment: I'm not familiar with $data... a little research shows it has something to do with ng-table? According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29508201/215552) it's been deprecated, so I'm afraid I don't know what's up.

Comment: You know what, that might explain why it's working in my table an not outside of it, I think I need to read a bit more on template variables. Thanks.

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Hierarchies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-hierarchies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the original developer was using getData() method to populate a $data object from what I can understand, whose scope is only the table contained within the view. Seems to be deprecated and poorly documented so it was a little confusing, and that's why I couldn't access the $data variable anywhere in the view.